# StreamWriter adds extra character(s) on new line(s) at the end of file

Tags: c#, .net, file-writing

I'm trying to modify an .ini file, in C# with .NET 5.0, using FileStream and StreamReader / StreamWriter. I just need to modify the first line of the file so I read the entire file into a list of strings called `strList`, modify the first line, and then write it all back to the same file.

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\MyFolder\test.ini"))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            strList.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}

strList[0] = "test01";

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\MyFolder\test.ini"))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < ewsLines.Count; x++)
        {          
            sw.WriteLine(strList[x]);            
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that I'll have new character(s) at the end of my file on new line(s). I verified that the number of lines I read from the file matches what is in the file and that the for loop only writes that same number of lines back into the file. I don't have any issues writing other strings except for **"test01"**. This string is the only one that causes the issue that I just described. It seems to be grabbing characters from the last line like `R` or `LAYER` from `MULTI_LAYER`.

Ex 1: This

```
S10087_U1
Cq4InEq=TRUE
XtrVer=5.5
IOCUPDATEMDB=TRUE
ARCHITECTURE=MULTI_LAYER
```

Becomes this

```
test01
Cq4InEq=TRUE
XtrVer=5.5
IOCUPDATEMDB=TRUE
ARCHITECTURE=MULTI_LAYER
R
```

Ex 2: This

```
test01 - Copy
Cq4InEq=TRUE
XtrVer=5.5
IOCUPDATEMDB=TRUE
ARCHITECTURE=MULTI_LAYER
ER
```

Becomes this

```
test01
Cq4InEq=TRUE
XtrVer=5.5
IOCUPDATEMDB=TRUE
ARCHITECTURE=MULTI_LAYER
LAYER
```

Replacing the StreamWriter portion with the following seems to fix the issue but I'm trying to figure out why using StreamWriter doesn't work as I expect it to.

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFolder\test.ini", strList);
```

Comment: "*The [`OpenWrite` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=net-6.0#remarks) opens a file if one already exists for the file path, or creates a new file if one does not exist. For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. **If you overwrite a longer string (such as "This is a test of the `OpenWrite` method") with a shorter string (such as "Second run"), the file will contain a mix of the strings ("Second runtest of the OpenWrite method")**.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using `File.OpenWrite`. From the remarks in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=net-6.0):

> The `OpenWrite` method opens a file if one already exists for the file path, or creates a new file if one does not exist. For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you overwrite a longer string (such as "This is a test of the `OpenWrite` method") with a shorter string (such as "Second run"), the file will contain a mix of the strings ("Second runtest of the OpenWrite method").

While you *could* just change your code to use `File.Create` instead, I'd suggest changing the code more significantly - not just the writing, but the reading too:

```cs
string path = @"C:\MyFolder\test.ini";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
lines[0] = "test01";
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

That's *much* simpler code to do the same thing.

The half-way house between the two would be to use `File.OpenText` (to return a `StreamWriter`) and `File.CreateText` (to return a `StreamWriter`). There's no need to do the wrapping yourself.